# Sustain in Pure Data for libpd with xcode

Tags: patch, sample, envelope, piano, puredata

I'm working on a patch that plays samples from a piano, which works in xcode to build an piano app for ipad. I'm trying to add an adsr to create sustain, but I can't seem to get it working. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Patch:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4-qHDgzbDB3VUlwM09FSEowZWM/edit

Answer (score 2):

The ADSR is just an evelope which you are using to multiply the sound output with. However it is meant to be on a temporal axis together with the trigger of the sound. When I look at your patch I notice another thing: Why are you reloading the samples into the arrays every time you trigger them? The arrays should be filled on startup of the app, like this:

```
[loadbang]
|
[read -resize c1.wav c1Array(
|
[soundfiler]
```

Later, when you actually just want to play back, you do

```
[r c1]
|
[t b]
|
[tabplay~ c1Array]
|
[throw~]
```

and at one central point in your patch you can have

```
[catch~]
|
[dac~]
```

(add the main voulme there). Notice there are no connections between the three parts!